# Web upload to FTP

Tags: wordpress, web, upload, ftp

I want to create a landing page for a movie festival. Visitors should be able to upload their videos on our FTP server.

We're running a Wordpress setup, but we don't need to use it for the landing page.

Do you guys know any tools, plugins, scripts etc, that do this job?

Comment: Recommendation questions are off-topic, see [help/on-topic]. Research this site and you'll find tons of techniques. Try to implement one and come back if you get stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this, http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp it might help. I made something similar recently, and used php... don't know about using wordpress though.

Comment: Sounds promising. I'll give it a try.
I found this Wordpress plugin: http://wordpress.org/plugins/nmedia-user-file-uploader/screenshots/ but the free version has too few features. Before paying 30 bucks, i'm gonna try writing exactly what i want by myself ;)

Answer (score 0):

One of the easiest ways to do it would probably be to use Amazon S3, they have an easy to use API for PHP and you can pay for exact usage that way. Your new video page would have a simple file upload section, then use PHP to save uploaded vids to Amazon S3 via their API and then you can display the videos embedded and the urls are actually links to the files on Amazon's servers.

Comment: Moving to an other provider is not possible, so this solution doesnt work for me. Thanks anyways ;)

Comment: You wouldn't be moving to another provider. Amazon S3 is a cloud service that you can use with any provider you desire.